# django date range from today and 10 days back

Tags: python, django, date

I have a model:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
description = models.TextField()
post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here I want to display the questions that has posted within 10 days like

```
Question.objects.filter(post_date__range=(today, 10 days back))
```

How can I do this ??

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
today = datetime.today()
Question.objects.filter(
    post_date__range=(today-datetime.timedelta(days=10), today)
)
```

something like this should work.

You can do addition/substration of date times with the [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) module.

Comment: global name today is not defined :)

Comment: I think this is `datetime.today`

Comment: @aryan, I assumed `today` was a variable already defined in your code, will update answer.